# Rowbind List of lists in R

Tags: r, list, append, row, bind

I have a list of lists like **out**. In each list of list I have a dataframe (with the same structure, i.e. same variables).

```
out <- replicate(4, rep(list(NULL), 2), simplify = FALSE)
```

My desire is to rowbind all dataframes belonging to first list of lists, the second together (in my original exercise I have more than a 4 lists of 2 lists... For this example I would do something like the following:

```
dataframe1 <- rbind(out[[1]][[1]], out[[2]][[1]], out[[3]][[1]], out[[4]][[1]])
dataframe2 <- rbind(out[[1]][[2]], out[[2]][[2]], out[[3]][[2]], out[[4]][[2]])
```

Any idea on how to do it iteratively and more elegantly?

PS:  Sorry for not sharing real data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach using `rlist` and `purr`

```
do.call(rlist::list.zip, out) %>%
 purrr::map(~ do.call(rbind, .))
```

Or, with even more `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)

out %>%
  do.call(rlist::list.zip, .) %>%
  map(~ reduce(., rbind))
```

Comment: Thank you for the correct and fast answer!!

Answer (score 1):

When your frames are all structured similarly or the same and you intend to to the same "thing" to all of them, it is generally best to work with a [list of frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227) instead of individual elements.

```r
out <- replicate(4, rep(list(mtcars[c(1,3),1:3]), 2), simplify = FALSE)
out[[1]][[1]]
#             mpg cyl disp
# Mazda RX4  21.0   6  160
# Datsun 710 22.8   4  108

lapply(1:2, function(ind) do.call(rbind, lapply(out, `[[`, ind)))
# [[1]]
#              mpg cyl disp
# Mazda RX4   21.0   6  160
# Datsun 710  22.8   4  108
# Mazda RX41  21.0   6  160
# Datsun 7101 22.8   4  108
# Mazda RX42  21.0   6  160
# Datsun 7102 22.8   4  108
# Mazda RX43  21.0   6  160
# Datsun 7103 22.8   4  108
# [[2]]
#              mpg cyl disp
# Mazda RX4   21.0   6  160
# Datsun 710  22.8   4  108
# Mazda RX41  21.0   6  160
# Datsun 7101 22.8   4  108
# Mazda RX42  21.0   6  160
# Datsun 7102 22.8   4  108
# Mazda RX43  21.0   6  160
# Datsun 7103 22.8   4  108
```

If you're already using `dplyr` or `data.table`, then these are relatively equivalent but often a little safer:

```r
lapply(1:2, function(ind) data.table::rbindlist(lapply(out, `[[`, ind), fill = TRUE, use.names = TRUE))
lapply(1:2, function(ind) dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(out, `[[`, ind)))
```